# When does Allegiant Air add flights?

Tags: airlines, bookings, allegiant-air

I've been trying to buy Allegiant Air tickets for an August 20 trip for several weeks now and every time I check their website I see the following:

> Displaying all available flight dates.
>
> Now accepting reservations through Tue Aug 15, 2017.

At first I thought that only showed flights like 7 months in advance or some such. Under that hypothesis they'd have added the August 20 flights a few days after I initially checked. But nope - a few weeks has passed and I'm still seeing that message.

So now I'm wondering...  when will tickets for flights after August 15 be available for purchase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this forum [thread](http://www.disboards.com/threads/when-will-allegiant-air-release-dates.2675697/) in 2011, someone actually called Allegiant over this:

> I called back in the middle of Jan. and was told the middle of March.

Comment: Keep in mind that Allegiant operates somewhat more flexibly that other carriers so allow some flexibility in your plans.

Answer (score 7):

You don't indicate where you are proposing to fly from/to so a [general answer](https://www.allegiantair.com/reservations-ticketing):

> **When will you announce new dates or routes?**
>
> Can’t find your favorite route on the flight calendar? Some flight routes are seasonal. Click here to view the interactive route map.
>
> Sign up for email notifications to be the first to find out about deals, upcoming schedule extensions and route announcements!

That is, there may be no flights on your route after August 15, 2017, at least not until the new season. Seasonal routes can be seen [here](https://www.allegiantair.com/interactive-routemap) (supposedly).

Comment: Las Vegas, NV to Grand Island, NE. When clicking on Grand Island, NE on that map it looks like only Florida flight is seasonal? But I could be wrong - it looks like it has tiny spaces throughout the line making me think it's a dashed line but the spaces are quite tiny idk

Answer (score 2):

Airlines add dates based on their own preferences.  Some add dates in advance and open bookings for so many days in the future.  Some add dates every week or every month.  Some add dates based on season, such as all summer dates at one time.